# How to solve these about SharedPreference?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, retrofit2, okhttp

I read a post about Sharedpreference to use auto-login using retrofit2 and Okhttp3.

I learned and copied code from googling, like

```
public class AddCookiesInterceptor implements Interceptor {


    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request.Builder builder = chain.request().newBuilder();

        // author said it's for getting cookies. But i can't understand, can't use this code
        Set<String> preferences =  SharedPreferenceBase.getSharedPreference(APIPreferences.SHARED_PREFERENCE_NAME_COOKIE, new HashSet<String>());

        for (String cookie : preferences) {
            builder.addHeader("Cookie", cookie);
        }

        return chain.proceed(builder.build());
    }
}
```

codes from : http://gun0912.tistory.com/50

From these, What i can't understand and don't know is `Set<String> preferences =  SharedPreferenceBase.getSharedPreference(APIPreferences.SHARED_PREFERENCE_NAME_COOKIE, new HashSet<String>());` This part.

1. What `SharedPreferenceBase` and `APIPreferences.SHARED_PREFERENCE_NAME_COOKIE` means?
2. I want to know where and how do i write SharedPreferenceBase for that code.

If i write SharedPreference on my Loginactivity or Mainactivity, i can't get it in right way to my AddCookiesInterceptor from those activities. Cause of my poor level of programming.

Comment: Sorry, but the questions you ask don't make much sense, hence it's hard to answer them properly. Probably you should do more Java programming and take entry level Android courses (e.g. Udacity) before diving into this kind of stuff.

Comment: oh, Thank you. I will do more effort.